# R: Error when using viewRGB() and editMap()

Tags: spatial, r-raster, r-mapview, r-mapedit

Below is the code I am using:

```
if (interactive()) {
  library(raster)
  library(plainview)

  viewRGB(plainview::poppendorf, 4, 3, 2) # true-color
  viewRGB(plainview::poppendorf, 5, 4, 3) # false-color
}
```

I got the following error message:

```
Error in leafem::addHomeButton(map = map, ext = ext, layer.name = layer.name,  : 
unused argument (layer.name = layer.name)
In addition: Warning message:
'mapview::addHomeButton' is deprecated.
Use 'leafem::addHomeButton' instead.
See help("Deprecated") and help("mapview-deprecated").
```

Any help is much appreciated!

-Zhou

Comment: This is a temporary issue that should be solved with the upcoming **mapview** CRAN release, hopefully this weekend. In the meantime, you can `remotes::install_github("r-spatial/mapview@develop")` to resolve this.

Comment: `remotes::install_github("r-spatial/mapview@develop")` solved my problem!  Thank you for the very quick help. @TimSalabim